Formulating isometric deformations and ricci flow together
I want to see if it's possible if an isometric deformation to a surface can be encapsulated in ricci flow.
A helicoid and catenoid are examples of flexible surfaces that can be isometrically deformed into one another parametrically. For the following transformation, one can see that as we vary $\alpha$ we transform the surface from a helicoid to a catenoid.
\begin{equation}
x(u,v) = \cos \alpha \sinh v \sin u + \sin \alpha \cosh v \cos u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y(u,v) = -\cos \alpha \sinh v \cos u + \sin \alpha \cosh v \sin u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z(u,v) = u \cos \alpha + v \sin \alpha
\end{equation}
Is it possible to show that the metric induced by these equations would satisfy the ricci flow equation $\partial_\alpha g = -2R_{ij}$?
My attempt so far to get started and hopefully generalize later has been to replace the sines and cosines in $\alpha$ with functions $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ so I can write the induced metric as $(f(\alpha)^2 + g(\alpha)^2)*\cosh^2 v (dv^2 + du^2)$. What's nice about isometric deformations, at least in the case of the helicoid/catenoid, is that the induced metric never changes: $\forall \alpha, \ ds^2 = \cosh^2 (v)(dv^2 + du^2)$. Furthermore, since the surface is two-dimensional, we can simplify the ricci flow equation to $(\partial_\alpha + R)g = 0$ for ricci scalar $R$. Trying to solve for $f$ and $g$ to prove they're indeed sine and cosine gives:
$$
ff' + gg' = \DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech} \sech^4v 
$$
But this doesn't make too much sense since the LHS is solely a function of $\alpha$ and RHS solely a function of a single coordinate. I don't think I can validly make use of a separation constant and additionally choose it to be $0$ to get my desired functions for f and g. If for an isometric deformation the induced metric has to remain unchanged, perhaps the evolution of the deformation and ricci flow aren't reconcilable.

The Ricci flow deforms the metric. A metric remains unchanged (I.e., the metric at time $t$ is isometric to the original metric) if and only if the Ricci curvature is zero. For a surface this holds if and only if the Gauss curvature is zero.
In your example, as you say, all of the metrics in the flow are isometric to the original one. Therefore, it is a Ricci flow only if the Gauss curvature is zero. But that’s not the case. So the flow is not a Ricci flow.

@Deane oh I see. Is it true then that the evolution of an isometric deformation for any surface is never a Ricci flow? I guess what I'm really asking is is it true that isometric deformations always leaves the metric invariant? I take it that Ricci flow is an explicit statement on how curvature evolves parametrically for given some deformations?

I apologize. I spoke too soon. The Ricci flow of a metric can be a family of isometric metrics. They are call ed steady solisons. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_soliton. So it is possible that your example is an example. See if you can figure this out. If not, revise this question or post a new one.

@Deane ah interesting. thank you. I made a new post working out the details. I think I'm close. It'd be great if you could take a look. Thanks for your help, it's been insightful
